# problem with 22.04.2: starting apps in wayland with dedicated graphic card (mine: nvidia, integrated intel)

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, wayland

In 22.04.1 the gnome desktop is executed with the integrated intel graphic card as default. It does not matter if I choose X11 or wayland to display the gnome desktop. Therefore I prefer wayland as this is the future (well, since almost a decade, but ok, good things need time ;) ). Then I found the command `__NV_PRIME_RENDER_OFFLOAD=1 __GLX_VENDOR_LIBRARY_NAME=nvidia ./bin/release/myapp` for starting my 3d simulation with the dedicated nvidia graphic card again (which uses btw. the closed source driver - the main reason because the app is visually more appealing than with the open source driver).

Some days ago I was forced to upgrade to 22.04.2. I thought this does not matter anything as this is just a little upgrade in this LTS itself. But I was wrong and now I can not start my generated app with the dedicated card.

Gnome settings itself says that it installed nvidia driver 535 fully without problems. But I do not know how to use it. Every time I try `__NV_PRIME_RENDER_OFFLOAD=1 __GLX_VENDOR_LIBRARY_NAME=nvidia ./bin/release/myapp`, bash tells me that my app "Failed to create GLFW window". But this works, if I execute `./bin/release/myapp` (then as default my internal intel card with its open source driver is used).

Is there another way to execute an app with the dedicated graphic card in wayland? Suddenly has wayland no right to create GLFW windows for the dedicated graphic card? Or what is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting, no one knew a solution or did not understand, what I asked?

Myself I found a solution and I post it here for others who perhaps have this problem like me in earlier times:

Somehow an upgrade in Ubuntu (22.04 LTS!) removed the package 'nvidia-cuda-toolkit' as described as this [Website Starbeam about running apps with dedicated graphic card](https://starbeamrainbowlabs.com/blog/article.php?article=posts%2F436-running-application-on-nvidia.html) told that this is needed. So with Synaptic Package Manager I installed back again this toolkit and "Voila!", from terminal I could start my developed app back again on wayland with the nvidia card and his nvidia driver.